# Twig path() function not working in Symfony2.7 error 404 template

Tags: php, symfony

In a template, I generate the url's to other pages like:

```
<a href="{{ path('testdrivesList', {'edition': edition.name}) }}" itemprop="url">
```

This works perfect in a normal page. The generated url will be /ww/testdrives, where ww is the edition name.

However, in a custom 404 template that extends the site template, the url becomes 'http://testdrives'.

Why and how can I fix this?